# ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I merged many dataframes into bigger one,

`pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)`

then I can **not** dump it into **json**

```
(Pdb) df.to_json()
*** ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='columns'.
```

How could I fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Well the error is pretty self-explanatory, do you really want your index values to be a series of repeating text values?

Answer (score 39):

The error indicates that your dataframe index has non-unique (repeated) values.  Since it appears you're not using the index, you could create a new one with:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

or

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

if you want to remove the previous index.

Check this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-reset-index) as well.

Answer (score 8):

Pandas provide different strategies to format data in JSON.
The 'orient' parameter has 5 allowed values as described here: [Pandas IO tools documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-json).
The 'index' and 'columns' strategy requires unique index, while the others not.

Another solution is possible if you have a primary key you can modify the index of the DataFrame.
eg.

```
df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])
```

Example here: [Set multi column index in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208610/set-multi-column-index-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me:

```
df.to_json(orient="split")
```

Comment: in my case orient="records" did the job.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had duplicate columns in my pandas DataFrame. I read from a SQL query that did a join on two columns, which is allowed but becomes problematic when you want to create a JSON. Drop the columns:

`df = df.drop(columns="duplicate_column")`

Or simply rename them

`df.rename(index=str, columns={"duplicate_column": "duplicate_column_2"})`

In my case where I used SQL it's better to change the query to not return the duplicate column you are joining on.

Answer (score -2):

Could try dropping duplicates.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```