# Set multi column index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I make dataframe like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'class' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'number' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
    'math' : [90, 20, 50, 30, 57, 67, 89, 79, 45, 23],
    'english' : [40, 21, 68, 89, 90, 87, 89, 54, 21, 23]
})
```

and i want to convert index to this by using some pandas methods.(ex. set_index, stack,,,)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (5, 4)),
             columns = [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],['english', 'math', 'english', 'math']],
             index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshaping, then swap levels in `MultiIndex` in columns by [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and last sort columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['number','class']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_index(1)

print (df1)
class        A            B     
       english math english math
number                          
1           40   90      87   67
2           21   20      89   89
3           68   50      54   79
4           89   30      21   45
5           90   57      23   23
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.set_index(['number','class']).stack().unstack([1,2]))
class        A            B     
       english math english math
number                          
1           40   90      87   67
2           21   20      89   89
3           68   50      54   79
4           89   30      21   45
5           90   57      23   23
```

Comment: nice. I missed the set_index part somehow, but that's important! Works great.

Comment: How to set 3 columns as index?

Comment: @William - Use `df.set_index(['number','class', 'col3'])`

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but I tried and it not working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855070/pandas-how-to-set-multiple-columns-as-index?noredirect=1#comment121688317_68855070

Comment: @William - I see, `pivot_table` is possible use there?

Comment: @William - If use `pivot_table` what is error?

Answer (score 12):

I like @jezrael answer a lot, but just for completeness - you can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) instead of `set_index` + `unstack`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='number', columns='class').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(1)
class        A            B     
       english math english math
number                          
1           40   90      87   67
2           21   20      89   89
3           68   50      54   79
4           89   30      21   45
5           90   57      23   23
```