# read_excel in pandas giving error for no header and multiple index_col's

Tags: python, pandas, header

This code is giving me an error in Pandas:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1,header=None, index_col=[0,1])
```

...gives this error:

> Error:     offset = 1 + header TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)
>   for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

If I have only one index col its working fine:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1,header=None, index_col=0)
```

Or if I have multiple index column with header its working fine:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1,index_col=[0,1])
```

So, how to define multiple index column with no header. The issue here is internally the code is trying to add 1 to header (which is None) in case of multiple index and its failing.

File content:
row 1: p  w  1  2
row 2: q  x  3  4

Comment: please put your `file1` content here.

Comment: Please add it into your question. No one can figure out where the spaces and newlines are like that.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to figure out how to add table in question. There are simply 2 rows. I have added it in question.

Comment: Please post your file contents. Otherwise noone can answer you - we need to see the exact spaces, newlines and separators. Try opening in Excel and saving as CSV.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug from pandas that has been reported [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31783). It will be fixed in pandas v1.1.

Note that this was happening independently of the file being read.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:** read_excel and create index separately:

```
  df1 = pd.read_excel(file1,header=None) 
  df1.set_index([0,1],inplace=True)
```

Still not sure how to do that in one line.

Comment: Seems like there was a pandas parser error, but since you never showed us your file contents like multiple people asked you to, we can't see the exact spaces, newlines and separators, so this isn't a very reusable resource for other users. (Also, please state the pandas version, and retry with the current version and confirm if this still happens)

Answer (score -1):

`df1 = pd.read_excel(file1,header=None, index_col=0)` should work in this case.

`index_col=0` indicates that first column must be treated as `index` for your `dataframe`.

Refer:
[Different read_csv index_col = None / 0 / False in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862864/different-read-csv-index-col-none-0-false-in-pandas)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Yes its working fine for one index column. But what if I want multiple index column with no header. Is there any solution?

Comment: In this case I suppose you need to go for unstack() or pivot_table(). May be the below discussion would help you. I haven't tried this yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208610/set-multi-column-index-in-pandas

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. What the OP describes is a know bug from pandas reported here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31783