# What's the cause of the Pandas error on read.excel header=None, multiple index_col's

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is related to this SO question: [read_excel in pandas giving error for no header and multiple index_col's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334347/read-excel-in-pandas-giving-error-for-no-header-and-multiple-index-cols)

**But instead of a workaround, I would like to know why this is happening.** The data frame:

[image]

The data:

```
{0: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'C', 8: 'C'},
 1: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 1.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 2.0},
 2: {0: 'AA1', 1: 'a', 2: 'ng/mL', 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 3: {0: 'AA2', 1: 'a', 2: nan, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 4: {0: 'BB1', 1: 'b', 2: nan, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 5: {0: 'BB2', 1: 'b', 2: 'mL', 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 6: {0: 'CC1', 1: 'c', 2: nan, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 7: {0: 'CC2', 1: 'c', 2: nan, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}}
```

Reading the data like:

```
pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=3, index_col=[0, 1], header=None)
```

Does not work:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is given in the full traceback:

```
  ....
  File "D:\Programme\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 473, in parse offset = 1 + header
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

`header` is set to `None` and in calculating the offset it tries to add `1` to `None` which results in a `TypeError`. I think it's simply a bug.

**The following is absolutely without any warranty:**
line 473 of ...\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py should be changed from `offset = 1 + header` to `offset = 1 + header if header is not None else -1` to make multiple index columns work with `header=None`